# Outlook Web App / OWA dosent meet the security policy

Tags: internet-explorer, outlook-web-access, web-application

Im having big time trouble accessing a Outlook Web App / OWA page on one computer. Accessing the website gives me most of the time the following error.

[image: Error using Internet Explorer]

I do not have access to the OWA / Exchange configuration but i think this may be a client problem because i have a second pc where it works fine. Using differen browsers show me java applett error and that i should install/update java.

PC where it does not work:

- up to date internet explorer 11
- 64 bit windows 7

PC where its works:

- up to date internet explorer 11
- 64 bit windows 8

What i tested:

- checked internet setting / compare them to the pc where it works
- resetted internet settings
- cleared internet cache / cookies
- resetting internet explorer
- added owa site to trusted sites
- update java
- reinstall java
- java security settings changed
- enhanced protection mode is not enabled
- compare the advanced setting between the clients - no difference in configuration

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a problem for your IT department to fix ...

Comment: Im part of the it department.

Comment: Have you turned off enhanced protection mode? Also if you're in the IT department how come you can't access the OWA/exchange configuration?

Comment: The owa site we trying to access is an external one, not from our company. I allready contaced the it department there but as i mentioned as far as my tests going it seems to be a client issue. enhanced protection is not enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a good solution but when you set the internet explorer to delete all temp files, history and cookies on every programm close it works fine.

So my guess is that when you access the webapp  it will create some local stored file that seems to be somehow corrupt.